# Problem with changing the scenes in phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm making a game in phaser 3 with as a framework the game done by Michael Hadley in his Phaser 3/matter.js tutorial (https://itnext.io/modular-game-worlds-in-phaser-3-tilemaps-5-matter-physics-platformer-d14d1f614557) and I'm having a problem with changing scene at the end of the first level to make it transition to the second one. I divided all the game in .js modules as he did, so I've done the first and second level in two different .js files and added both of them as scenes on the index.js file that contains the config function:

```
import MainScene from "./main-scene.js";
import MainScene2 from "./main-scene2.js";

let config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 1280,
  height: 720,
  backgroundColor: "#000c1f",
  parent: "game-container",
  scene: [MainScene, MainScene2],
  pixelArt: true,
  physics: { default: "matter" },
  plugins: {
    scene: [
      {
        plugin: PhaserMatterCollisionPlugin, // The plugin class
        key: "matterCollision", // Where to store in Scene.Systems, e.g. scene.sys.matterCollision
        mapping: "matterCollision" // Where to store in the Scene, e.g. scene.matterCollision
      }
    ]
  }
};

let game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

The two scenes begin like this:

```
export default class MainScene extends Phaser.Scene
```

And

```
export default class MainScene2 extends Phaser.Scene
```

and at the end of the MainScene scene there is the code that triggers the scene transition:

```
if(this.player.sprite.x > 15400){
    this.scene.start(MainScene2);
}
```

The problem that I find myself into is that when I try to run the game it shows a black screen saying:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot add a Scene with duplicate key: default
```

So I've tried removing the default in the second scene, then receiving the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './main-scene2.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

I've tried searching all the scenes tutorials on the phaser labs example page (https://labs.phaser.io/index.html?dir=&q=) but all of them don't show a default in the scene code. I've tried to read again the first tutorial that I used as a framework as he wrote the export code that I've used in the game but he doesn't say how can I add another level as a scene or how to not use the default export, which I've seen in other codes online but never fully understood. I even tried to merge all the three .js files together so putting the two scenes & the config file in the same file, but the error was the same.

I'm sure that the two scenes work fine when they are played alone, I just don't know how to connect them as first and second level.

I'm sure that the answer is really stupid and I'm doing something really wrong but I've tried searching a lot online but finding nothing similiar to this.

It's the first time I write a question here so I'm not sure if I'm giving enough informations, so I'm linking three code sandbox links here; the first one has the index.html and index.js to make only the first level work, the second one makes the second level work and the third one is the way that I tried to connect the two levels:

1: https://codesandbox.io/s/xv42ww7joo

2: https://codesandbox.io/s/l9zr5yqm49

3: https://codesandbox.io/s/2p22o6rnly

Thank you so much for your help in advance, it's only been a month or so since I've been using phaser and I'm having a hard time understanding some things, but since now I've always found an answer online but this has been troubling me for some time and I've found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a constructor to both scenes and call super with a key name.

So in MainScene it will be

```
constructor() {
  super("main");
}
```

In MainScene2 it will be

```
constructor() {
  super("main2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What tontheman answered is correct. Just want to add to that if you want to extend a `Phaser.Scene` you need to either pass a `string` as the key or an `Object` as the config. You can refer to [Phaser 3 API Documentation - Class:Scene](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scene.html#Scene__anchor) for more guidance.